# Rotation to an ImageView, inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#272727"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoMobile"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="2.2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/lin" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BtnSlide"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:text="HEADER"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

This xml defines a "Tab bar" ontop of the application, just beneath the notification bar. I want the `ImageView` to rotate around its center. I tried it this way in my `onCreate` method:

```
logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoMobile);
ApplyAnimationToObject doAnimation = new ApplyAnimationToObject(logo);
doAnimation.startRotationAnimation();
```

And then the `ApplyAnimationToObject` class:

```
package Logic;

public class ApplyAnimationToObject {

final ImageView image;

public ApplyAnimationToObject(ImageView image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void startRotationAnimation() {
    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(7000);
    image.startAnimation(anim);
  }
}
```

But the ImageView will not rotate or have any animation at all. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**

I tried using this code:

```
public void rotateView(View v){
    Animation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0,
            360, v.getWidth() / 2, v.getWidth() / 2);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(10000);
    v.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    if(rotateAnimation.hasEnded())
        Log.i("+++++ANIMATION+++++", "ENDED!!");
    else
        Log.i("+++++++ANIMATION++++++", "NOT ENDED");
}
```

And the output til `LogCat` tells me that the animation hasn't ended yet, but there is no animation to the `ImageView`

Answer (score 3):

try the following code:

```
     Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
     imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
     matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
     imagView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try another way also:

Use RotateAnimation on the View you want to Rotate, and make sure the Animation set to fillAfter=true, duration=0, and fromDegrees=toDgrees

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:toDegrees="45"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="0"
    android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

and Inflate the Animation in code:

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
myView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `ImageView` will remain static in this case aswell. Do I need to put it in a thread to make it rotate several times?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code :

```
public void rotateView(View v){
    Animation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0,
            360, v.getWidth() / 2, v.getWidth() / 2);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
    v.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

To call for rotation :

```
rotateView(imgView);
```